# PhpStorm "waiting for localhost": PHP page won't load (was working earlier)

Tags: webserver, localhost, phpstorm

Using PhpStorm, I ran into a case during development where suddenly new PHP scripts that were opened were resulting in "waiting for localhost" in Chrome, with no other activity.

Answer (score 0):

It turns that prior to my issue I had run a PHP script the same way with a very long processing loop in it, and closed out of it instead of waiting for it to load in Chrome.

When I went to the "**Activity Monitor**" in MacOS I saw a `php-cgi` process taking up 90-95% CPU. After I killed it, I could open new PHP scripts in Chrome as usual.